# AngularJs call to JAX-RS Service returning a (415 Unsupported Media Type)

Tags: angularjs, rest, csv, jax-rs

I've been struggling with this the whole day and can't get my hands onthe problem.
I got a JAX-RS webservice that is supposed to return a CSV file in a byteArray Format to an ANgularJS client : the Service Code is the following

```
@POST
@Path("/{id_user}/transactionsCsv")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM})
@ApiOperation(value = "Transactions de l'utilisateur connecté sous forme   CSV",response = byte[].class)
@RolesAllowed(value = SecurityRoles.PORTAIL_ACTIVITE_RUBRIQUE)
public Response getOperationsCsv(@PathParam("id_user") long id_user,
                              @Context HttpServletRequest request, final TransactionFiltreDTO filtre) throws MalformedURLException {    

    //CsvContent is a StringBuilder converted to a byte array 
    byte [] CsvContent = csvExportService.buildCsv();

    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(new ByteArrayInputStream(CsvContent));

    response.header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, 
                    "attachment; filename="+"activite"+".csv")
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/csv");

    return response.build();
```

}

And this is my AngularJS Call :

```
 fetchCsv: function() {
     return $http({
       url: SERVER_CONTEXT + '/rest/utilisateurs/' + Session.id + '/transactionsCsv',
       method: 'POST',
       params: {},
       headers: {
         'Content-type': 'application/csv'
       },
       responseType: 'arraybuffer',
       timeout: '20000'
     });
   },
```

The probelm here is That the call returns a : **415 (Unsupported Media Type)** ! 
Can anyone tell me if I'm missing something on my server side or client side code here ? 
Thanks :)

Comment: text/csv is the normal content-type for csv. You might want to try that

Comment: Tried text/csv but still returning the same error

Comment: `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` also suggest a different content type again. Furthermore, you're using POST for what should have been GET. You're also not sending any text/csv in your body (implying you need a Content-Type) but you're requesting it (implying you need an Accept header). This is all coming from someone who never has written java or JAX-RS. But those are a bunch of problems I see on the surface.

Comment: I've tried all the combinations possible but nothing seems to work :/ Any other areas i can explore ?

Comment: It's hard to tell if you made those changes correctly because the question here is still the same. I'm almost positive it has to do with your incorrect handling of content-type/accept headers.